# Query selects duplicated records

Tags: mysql, duplicates, record

I want to select all records from `website.advert` and join player name from different table also. The query runs itself without any errors, but there is a problem that it does select duplicated records from `website.advert` **when** there is more than one record with the same `account_id` in the player table.

Here is my query:

```
  SELECT `advert`.*, `p`.`name`, `p`.`level`
   FROM `website`.`advert`
   LEFT JOIN `player`.`player` `p`
   ON (`p`.`account_id` = `website`.`advert`.`author_id`)
   WHERE `advert`.`accepted` = 0
```

Comment: You need to use the GROUP BY clause on `advert.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DISTINCT` but I am having trouble figuring out your query. You don't seem to be selecting any fields from `website.advert`

Sorry, edited:

```
SELECT `advert`.*, `p`.`name`, `p`.`level`
 FROM `website`.`advert`
 LEFT JOIN `player`.`player` `p`
 ON (`p`.`account_id` = `website`.`advert`.`author_id`)
 WHERE `advert`.`accepted` = 0
 GROUP BY `advert`.`id`
```

We are JUST selecting the `id` field for now - try that and see if it gives you closer to the results you are expecting.

Comment: I'm selecting all fields from `website.advert` using: `SELECT advert.*`.

Comment: Okay, just never seen that way of selecting data before :) Try using `DISTINCT` around `advert.*`

Comment: @Your edited answer, returns error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* ), `p`.`name`, `p`.`level` FROM `website`.`advert` '`

Comment: I've used ` SELECT DISTINCT advert.*` instead, but it does still select duplicated rows from `advert`.\

Comment: Query works, but it still does select the duplicates :/.
When there is just one player with `account_id` same as `author_id` then its ok, but if there are two (or more) players with `account_id` like the `author_id` then it does select duplicates. Duplicates count is equal to the players with `account_id` same as `author_id` count.

Comment: Try that edited query. You will probably be best off using GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.*, p.name, p.level
   FROM advert a LEFT JOIN player p
   ON (p.account_id = a.author_id)
   WHERE a.accepted = 0
group by p.account_id
```